# How to fit a curve to a damped sine wave in matlab

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I have some measurements done and It should be a damped sine wave but I can't find any information on how to make (if possible) a good damped sine wave with Matlab's curve fitting tool.

Here's what I get using a "Smoothing spline":

[Image http://s21.postimg.org/yznumla1h/damped.png](http://s21.postimg.org/yznumla1h/damped.png).

**Edit 1**:
Here's what I got using the "custom equation" option:

[image]

**Edit 2**:
I've uploaded the data to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/LWb6akBe) in csv format where the first column is the amplitude and the second is the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The damped sin function can be created using the following code:

```
f=f*2*pi;
t=0:.001:1;
y=A*sin(f*t + phi).*exp(-a*t);

plot(t,y);
axis([0 1 -2.2 2.2]);
```

Now you can use "cftool" from matlab and load your data then set the equation type to custom and enter the formula of the damped sin function. Here you can see what I found so far...

[image]

I think the distribution of the data makes it hard for the fitting tool to do a good fit. It may need more data or more distributed data. In addition, there are other tools and methods as well, for instance check this for now: docstoc.com/docs/74524947/Mathcad-Damped-sine-fit-mcd

For all these methods that actually trying to search and find a local optimum (for each fitting parameters), the most important thing is the initial condition. I believe if you choose a good initial condition (initial guess), the fitting tool works well.

Good Luck

Comment: I know how to manually create some generic damped sine I just want cftool to find constants that will fit mine... I did try the custom equation option but it didn't work well for me, but maybe I'm doing it wrong see the edit please

Comment: I think with this result the fit will show a big result, You may reduce the damping ratio. What I see, the damping ratio is big, so the curve damps very early. You can multiply the damping ratio by a small number to force it to damp slower.

Comment: I can try it myself, if you can share a part of data..!

Comment: Sure! It'd be wonderful if you could. I've uploaded the data to pastebin in csv format where the first column is the amplitude and the second is time. [link](http://pastebin.com/LWb6akBe)

Comment: I think the distribution of the data makes it hard for the fitting tool to do a good fit. It may need more data or more distributed data. there are other tools and methods as well, for instance check this for now: http://www.docstoc.com/docs/74524947/Mathcad-Damped-sine-fit-mcd

Comment: For all these methods that actually trying to search and find a local optimum, the most important thing is the initial condition. I believe if you choose a good initial condition, the fitting tool works well.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use the curve fitting toolbox for this, I'd use a curve-fitting function, e.g. `lsqcurvefit`. Here is an example taken from something I did a while back:

```
% Define curve model functions
expsin = @(a, f, phi, tau, t)a * sin(omega * t + phi) .* exp(-tau * t);
lsqexpsin = @(p, t)expsin(p(1), p(2), p(3), p(4), t);

% Setup data params
a = 1;          % gain
f = 10;         % frequency
phi = pi/2;     % phase angle
tau = 0.9252523;% time constant

fs = 100;   % sample rate
N = fs;     % length
SNR = 10;   % signal to noise ratio

% Generate time vector
dt = 1/fs; 
t = (0:N-1)*dt; 

omega = 2 * pi * f; % angular freq
noiseGain = 10^(-SNR/20); % gain for given SNR

% Generate dummy data: decaying sinusoid plus noise
x = expsin(a, omega, phi, tau, t);
noise = noiseGain * rand(size(x));
noise = noise - mean(noise);
x = x + noise;

close all; figure; hold on;
plot(t, x, 'k-', 'LineWidth', 2);

% Count zero crossings to find frequency
zCross = find(x(1:end-1) .* x(2:end) < 0);
T = mean(diff(zCross) * dt) * 2;
fEstimate = 1 / T;
omegaEstimate = 2 * pi * fEstimate;

% Fit model to data
init = [0.5, omegaEstimate, 0, 0.5];
[newparams, err] = lsqcurvefit(lsqexpsin, init, t, x);

plot(t, lsqexpsin(newparams, t))
```

Here some data with known parameters is generated, and some random noise added; the data is plotted. The parameters `[a, phi, tau]` are estimated from the data and a curve with the estimated parameters plotted on top.