# Matlab Finding Damped Sine wave decay factor for a given frequency

Tags: matlab, equation, trigonometry

how to find decay constant value of a damped sine wave for a given frequency in matlab?

```
t=0:1e-6:0.1;
f= 500000;
y=sin(2*pi*f*t).*exp(-d*t);
```

---

i want to solve above equation for "d"

Comment: Hi Chowhan, the value of 'd' will be system dependent. Could you please give some more context?

Comment: Are you sure that you have your question right? If you want to solve for `d` at a given frequency then what is `y`? You're missing constraints. Otherwise, your equation can be solved for `d` with basic algebra. If you have a particular waveform, you could look into the [logarithmic decrement method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_decrement). Otherwise, I'm not sure that this is a Matlab question.

Comment: There is this SO question about curve fitting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16110185/how-to-fit-a-curve-to-a-damped-sine-wave-in-matlab (see @wakjah answer).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics, not computer programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first need to find the *envelope* of your oscillating function (the function that amplitude-modulates your sine). This can be done e.g. by rectifying the signal and then low-pass-filtering, but I choose to do a quick and dirty running maximum. After you found the envelope, there are various ways to fit an exponential function. I again chose a quick&dirty trick to do a first order polyfit to the log of the envelope. The code below works for the simple example you gave, but is might not work if you have an offset, if you choose `n` wrong, etc. It also won't give the best possible result in case of a noisy measurement.

```
fsamp = 1e5;
tmax = 0.1;
t=0:1/fsamp:tmax;
f = 12e3; %should be smaller than fsamp/2!
tau = 0.0765;
y=sin(2 * pi * f * t) .* exp(-t / tau);

%calculate running maximum
n = 20; %number of points to take max over
nblocks = floor(length(t) / n);
trun = mean(reshape(t(1:n*nblocks), n, nblocks), 1); %n-point mean
envelope = max(reshape(y(1:n*nblocks), n, nblocks), [], 1); %n-point max

%quick and dirty exponential fit, not the proper way in case of noise
p = polyfit(trun, log(envelope), 1);
tau_fit = -1/p(1);
k_fit = exp(p(2));

plot(t, y, trun, envelope, 'or', t, k_fit * exp(-t / tau_fit), '-k')
title(sprintf('tau = %g', tau))
```

Note that with exponential decay, it is more common to define the time-constant `tau = 1 / d`.

Comment: Nice. You may have figured out what was being asked. `envelope = abs(hilbert(y));` could also be used (with appropriate care for using whole period or trimming the output).